# Laravel search for records 7 days old only

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

i am trying to pull records that are 7 days old only , not older or earlier.
But its not working, i'm using Carbon.

```
->where(DB::raw('date(AppDate)'), Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a solution, but its not using Carbon.

```
 ->whereRaw('DATE(AppDate) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use `whereDate` for that :

```
->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
->get();
```

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses) :

> The whereDate method may be used to compare a column's value against a
>   date

PS : Since Laravel 5.3

Comment: @Marabox i forgot to mention i am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: it's ok it will hepl others witch uses laravel 5.3 or newer one ;)

Answer (score -1):

To sum my last 7 days of records:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
```

```
$Profitinsevendays = DB::table('n_profit_loss')->where('datetime', '>=', $date)->sum('profit_or_loss');
```