# How to get last 7 days records from database by special raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and that's my issue

I need to get last 7 days records from table Orders by special raw 'location_name'.

```
$name = \App\Order::whereBetween('working_time',[Carbon::today()->startOfWeek(),Carbon::today()->endOfWeek()])->get();
```

this code return last 7 days but I need to order by 'location_name'

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: **Im using laravel and thats my issue ** then use something else :)

Comment: One google search and you are done. ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel search for records 7 days old only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731298/laravel-search-for-records-7-days-old-only)

Comment: $name = \App\Order::whereBetween('working_time',[Carbon::today()->startOfWeek(),Carbon::today()->endOfWeek()])->get();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$name = \App\Order::whereBetween('working_time',[Carbon::today()->startOfWeek(),Carbon::today()->endOfWeek()])->orderBy('location_name')->get()
```